# Sass Ampersand nesting with pseudo selectors

Tags: css, sass

Trying to utlize the SASS Ampersand to get the following css output. It is not working when we use Ampersand with inside pesudo selector.

**CSS**

```
.test:first-child .test-image { display: block; }
```

**SASS**

```
.test {
    &:first-child {
        display: inline-block;
        &-image {
            display: block;
        }   
    }
}
```

Above code basically cascading the -image with first-child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the ampersand is just concatenating the parent with the child. If you want the compiled CSS to look like your example you need to do this:

```
.test {
    &:first-child &-image{
      display: block;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, it worked for me. A quick question, if first-child also have few css proerpties inside it then do i need to write a seperate nesting for first-child ?

Comment: That's a really good question. I just did some testing and it looks like you can do this: 

```.test {
    &:first-child {
        height: 20px;
        & .test-image {
            height: 30px;
        }    
    }
}```

I learned something new! If you could check my answer correct, that would be nice too~

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to achieve

```
.test:first-child .test-image { display: block; }
```

With your code it is getting compiled as this

```
.test:first-child-image {
    display: block;
}
```

Instead ,you can simply write it as this .

```
.test:first-child {
        .test-image {
            display: block;
        }   
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: you should use `:` before `first-child`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have mistaken how the ampersand works in Sass. The ampersand is essentially a shorthand for writing each outer selector and then adding the selector after it onto the end. As `.test-image` is distinct from `.test`, you should specify it as follows.

```
.test {
    &:first-child {
        .test-image {
            display: block;
        }   
    }
}
```

Compiles to

```
.test:first-child .test-image {
    display: block;
}
```